# Kivy on Android : keep local storage files after app updates

Tags: android, python, local-storage, updates, kivy

I've got an Android app written in Kivy (Python), which stores local files that should survive an app update (adb install -r).

If the files are stored in a subdirectory of the current directory ("data/data/app_name/files"), I see that they are deleted after update.

However after some experiments I could "solve" this by storing the files in the "data/data/app_name/shared_prefs" directory, which seems to be persistent after updates. By the way, I didn't check but maybe the "data/data/app_name/databases" also is.

Is there a cleaner way of doing things ?
I need to test if I can create a new folder not called shared_prefs nor databases under "data/data/app_name", and if it is persistent.

(this seems kind of a hack because those directories have another dedicated purpose, even though my app is not using them for this dedicated purpose right now)
(NB: I don't want to keep the files outside the app private directory)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple way (as in a build hook or similar) right now, but it's something we've specifically discussed in the last few days as the current situation has become a direct problem. I'm not sure what the resolution was, but there will probably be a change in python-for-android to fix it fairly soon.

If you want to keep up to date with this, ask on the kivy mailing list or irc. In particular, knapper_tech was making these changes.

Comment: Thanks inclement. I found this indeed, really recent :  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/k6q37jybBVs   . If you could point me to the best way to keep updated (mailing list, google support group ?)... By the way I'm using the stable release 1.8.0. Would it be necessary to use the kivy-daily version to get the correction of this issue as soon as it is released ? Do you recommend NOT to use the 'shared_prefs' directory until the correction is available ?

Comment: This issue would be updated in python-for-android, not kivy, so it's only important that you keep that up to date (if you use buildozer, just delete the .buildozer directory in your app directory, and it will re-pull it). I have no real recommendation in the mean time.